# Pivot table return null using laravel 5.7.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pivot-table

I have two `models` named: **League** ans **User**

There's a `pivot` table named: **`league_user`** contains this structure:

```php
id
user_id
league_id
joined_at
rank
payment_id
created_at
updated_at
```

This is my Models:

```php
class League extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'capacity', 'is_open', 'started_at', 'finished_at', 'is_free', 'price', 'level', 'user_id', 'closed_by', 'edited_by'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];


    /*
     * User Relationship
     */
    function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


    /*
     * Editor Relationship
     */
    public function editor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'edited_by');
    }

    /*
     * All users Relationship
     */
    public function all_users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('rank', 'joined_at');
    }
}
```

***And User Model:***

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'family', 'email', 'mobile', 'password', 'username', 'team', 'email_verified_at', 'mobile_verified_at', 'role_id'
        ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    /*
     * Roles ralationship
     */
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    /*
     * Question Relationship
     */
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    /*
     * League Relationship
     */
    public function leagues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(League::class);
    }


    /*
     * Setting Relationship
     */
    public function setting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserSetting::class);
    }


    /*
     * All Leagues that User Joined
     */
    public function all_leagues()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(League::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('rank', 'joined_at');
    }

}
```

Now when I want to access to the `rank` or `joined_at` in my pivot table, it seems something is wrong or at least I'm doing that in a wrong manner.

I tried this:

```
foreach ( $leagues as $league )
{
    $pivot[] = $league->pivot;
}

dd($pivot);
}
```

to check  my pivot behavior, and I did check `$league->pivot->rank` or `$league->pivot->joined_at` either, but `pivot` table seems to be **null**!

Can any one tell me what's wrong in my code?

I saw these links:

[laraveldaily](https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

[laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/many-to-many-relationship-with-extra-field)

[laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

and...

Comment: Pivot tables should never have extra columns belonging to some entity.

Comment: Please can you show how you're getting the `$leagues` variable for the foreach?

Comment: @RossWilson I did try two manner, first; using `League::orderBy('price', 'asc')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(10);` and second as this question's answer says: `#user = User::find(Auth;;User()->id)`, and `$user->leagues`

Comment: Ok. To be able to access the pivot information you will always need to load the relationship otherwise Laravel isn't going to know which pivot table you want. Also, just an FYI, there is no point doing `User::find(Auth::user()->id)` as `Auth::user()` will return that user (you're essentially loading the User model twice).

Answer (score 0):

if `league_user` table with primary key `['league_id', 'user_id']`, you should be able to access the leagues like

```
$user = user::find(1);
$leagues  = $user->leagues;
```

and can loop through

```
@foreach($leagues as $league)
    {{ $league->rank }}
    {{ $league->joined_at }}
@endofreach
```

For that in User model it should be

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function leagues()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\League');
    }
}
```

and in League model

```
class League extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)